# if else statement in render?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, button

I'm having some trouble with my code where I want a user to be taken to two specific pages after they click "Sign in" ONLY IF they haven't already gone through that process before. Those two pages, are below:

```
this.props.history.push('/decision-style');
this.props.history.push('/area-of-expertise');
```

How it works is, if they have already gone through the process of those two pages, I want them not to go through it again, and just to be redirected to our news page:

```
this.props.history.push('/news');
```

If they have gone through the process before, it will already have added their information in MongoDB in the documents "decisionStyle", and "role"

[This is /area-of-expertise. Only want them to see this, and /decision-style if they haven't done this before, and therefore, their info isn't in Mongo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8JKr.png)

I thought I could maybe create an if... else statement in render to do something similar to what I am trying to achieve. However, that wouldn't work, so I have this code below:

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {fact: null,
      badge: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      error: null,
      showRegistration: false,
      userAuthFlow: false,
      userData: {},
    }
  }

render() {
  const self = this;
  console.log(this.state.userData.decisionStyle);
  // Create Registration Form
  function RegistrationFormModal(props) {
    return (
      <Modal
        {...props}
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
          Sign Up
            <button className="closeBtn" onClick={self.handleCloseRegistration}></button>
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <Registration/>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    );
  }

  // Login page

  const {error, isLoaded, fact} = this.state;

  if (error) {
    return (
      <div>
 Error: {error.messages}
      </div>
    );
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return (
      <Spinner style={{'width': '200px', 'height': '200px', 'font-size': '50px'}} animation="border"/>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div id="Login">
        <Fade top>
          <h1 style={{'font-size': '50px'}}>CRCounter
          </h1>
          <p style={{'font-size': '32px'}}> {JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fact.fact))}</p>
          <p> - {JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fact.author))} - </p>
        </Fade>
        <Fade bottom>
          <div id="form">
            <form>

            </form>

            <button className="confirmBtn" userAuthFlow={self.state.userData.role !== null && self.state.userData.decisionStyle !== null ? true : false}onClick = {this.handleClick}>Sign in</button>
            <a id = "register" onClick={this.handleShowRegistration}>Don't have an account?</a>

            <p id = "registerNote" > You won't be able to access most parts of the platform without an account! </p>
          </div>
        </Fade>
        <RegistrationFormModal
          show={this.state.showRegistration}
        />
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

The code below I created to be mainly responsible for trying to achieve what I want, but it's not working and not sure why as I am a bit of a React noob.. lol

```
<button className="confirmBtn" userAuthFlow={self.state.userData.role !== null && self.state.userData.decisionStyle !== null ? true : false}onClick = {this.handleClick}>Sign in</button>
```

The rest of the code (and updated code as well)...

```
/* eslint-disable require-jsdoc */
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Login.css';
import Fade from 'react-reveal/Fade';
import Spinner from 'react-bootstrap/Spinner';
import axios from 'axios';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import Registration from './Registration';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {fact: null,
      badge: null,
      error: null,
      fact: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      showRegistration: false,
      userAuthFlow: false,
      userData: {},
    }
  }
handleClick = () => {
  this.props.history.push('/decision-style');
}

// Registration form
handleShowRegistration = () => {
  this.props.history.push('/news');
}


handleCloseRegistration = () => {
  this.setState({showRegistration: false});
}

componentDidMount(sub) {
  axios.get('/services/getuserdata', {
      params: {ID: sub},
    })
        .then((response) => {
          this.setState({userData: response.data});
        });

  // Get the facts that will be displayed under the CRCounter logo
  function getFacts() {
    return axios.get('/services/facts');
  };

  // Get the welcome badge for the user if they signded up successfully for the platform
  function getBadge() {
    return axios.get('/services/badge', {
      params: {
        name: 'welcome',
      },
    });
  }


  Promise.all([getFacts(), getBadge()])
      .then((results) => {
        const responseOne = results[0].data;
        const responseTwo = results[1].data;
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          fact: responseOne,
          badge: responseTwo,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          fact: {author: '', fact: ''}});
      });
}

handleClick() {};
handleCloseRegistration() {};
handleShowRegisteration() {};

render() {
  const { error, isLoaded, fact, showRegistration, userData } = this.state;
  const flow = userData.role && userData.decisionStyle;
  const parse = (str) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(str));
  // Create Registration Form
  const RegistrationFormModal = (props) => {
      return (
        <Modal
          aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
          centered
          {...props}
        >
          <Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
            Sign Up
              <button
                className="closeBtn"
                onClick={this.handleCloseRegistration}
              >
                Close Button
              </button>
            </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <Registration />
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      );
    };

  // Login page
  if (error) {
    return (
      <div>
 Error: {error.messages}
      </div>
    );
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return (
      <Spinner style={{'width': '200px', 'height': '200px', 'font-size': '50px'}} animation="border"/>
    );
  } else {
     return (
      <div id="Login">
        <Fade top>
          <h1 style={{ 'font-size': '50px' }}>CRCounter</h1>
          <p style={{ 'font-size': '32px' }}>{parse(fact.fact)}</p>
          <p> - {parse(fact.author)} - </p>
        </Fade>
        <Fade bottom>
          <div id="form">
            <form>

            </form>
            <button
              className="confirmBtn"
              onClick={this.handleClick}
              userAuthFlow={flow}
            >
              Sign in
            </button>
            <a
              id="register"
              onClick={this.handleShowRegistration}
            >
              Don't have an account?
            </a>
            <p id="registerNote" >
              You won't be able to access most parts of the platform without an account!
            </p>
          </div>
        </Fade>
        <RegistrationFormModal show={showRegistration} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking for falsy values, just check for truthy values instead.

Here, if we have `role` && `decisionStyle` then it is true, otherwise false.

The logical AND operator (&&) returns true if both operands are true and returns false otherwise.

```
self.state.userData.role && self.state.userData.decisionStyle
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your condition is a little off. It should be something like `userData.role && userData.decisionStyle;`. I also took the liberty of destructuring some of your code, using arrow functions, removing `self`, and a couple of other things!

### UPDATED

```
class Login extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      badge: null,
      error: null,
      fact: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      showRegistration: false,
      userAuthFlow: false, // do you need this?
      userData: {},
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     // existing code here
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    const { history } = this.props;
    const flow = userData.role && userData.decisionStyle;
    history.push(flow ? '/news' : '/decision-style');
  }

  handleShowRegistration = () => {
    this.setState({ showRegistration: true });
  }


  handleCloseRegistration = () => {
    this.setState({ showRegistration: false });
  }
  
  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, fact, showRegistration, userData } = this.state;
    const parse = (str) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(str));

    // Create Registration Form
    const RegistrationFormModal = (props) => {
      return (
        <Modal
          aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
          centered
          {...props}
        >
          <Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
            Sign Up
              <button
                className="closeBtn"
                onClick={this.handleCloseRegistration}
              >
                Close Button
              </button>
            </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <Registration />
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      );
    };

    // Login page
    if (error) return <div>Error: {error.messages}</div>;
    if (!isLoaded) return (
      return (
        <Spinner
          animation='border'
          style={{
            font-size: '50px',
            height: '200px',
            width: '200px',
          }}
        />
      );
    );

    return (
      <div id="Login">
        <Fade top>
          <h1 style={{ 'font-size': '50px' }}>CRCounter</h1>
          <p style={{ 'font-size': '32px' }}>{parse(fact.fact)}</p>
          <p> - {parse(fact.author)} - </p>
        </Fade>
        <Fade bottom>
          <div id="form">
            <form>

            </form>
            <button
              className="confirmBtn"
              onClick={this.handleClick}
            >
              Sign in
            </button>
            <a
              id="register"
              onClick={this.handleShowRegistration}
            >
              Don't have an account?
            </a>
            <p id="registerNote" >
              You won't be able to access most parts of the platform without an account!
            </p>
          </div>
        </Fade>
        <RegistrationFormModal show={showRegistration} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! The code does make sense and I tried implementing it but sadly still does not work. I may be missing something somewhere else in the code so I will post the rest of the code as well

Comment: I updated it. I didn't notice before that you tried to pass the `userAuthFlow` object to a native `button` element. That really won't give you the behavior you're seeking, so I moved the logic to the `handleClick` method. If the user has been through the flow before, it'll push them to the `/news` view. If not, it'll push them to the `/decision-style` view.

Comment: If it works, please mark it as the answer! Thanks. :)